# Undefine a command in LaTeX

Tags: latex-base

`LaTeX`, of course, has a protective mechanism that prevents you from doing some stupid things:

```
\newcommand\a{a}
\newcommand\a{b} %% LaTeX Error: Command \a already defined.
```

Of course, if you know what you're doing, then you can circumvent it with `\renewcommand`.  However, some commands have their own definition mechanisms:

```
\newcommand\a{a}
\DeclareMathOperator\a{a} %% LaTeX Error: Command \a already defined.
```

(and there is no `\RedeclareMathOperator`).  I've been getting around this by doing something awkward like:

```
\newcommand\a{a}
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathOperator\@a{a}
\let\a=\@a %% \let (and \def) circumvents LaTeX's protection
\makeatother
```

(Of course, the best thing to do would be to delete that original definition, but, in practice, it's in another package that I must include but whose source I do not control.)  However, it occurs to me that a hypothetical `\undef` command would do the job:

```
\newcommand\a{a}
\undef\a
\newcommand\a{b} %% No complaints
```

Does such a command exist?  If not, is there an easy way to write it?

Comment: @Sigur, yes, it looks like it.  (If you post it as an answer, then I'll be happy to accept it.)  Sorry, that was a silly question!

Comment: (Oops, Sigur's comment went away; it pointed out that `\let\a=\relax` would do what I wanted.)

Comment: @LSpice. You can delete/answer your question if you wish.

Comment: @Sigur, thanks.  Is it better to delete it?  In terms of an answer, I'd rather accept your answer than repeat it myself.

Comment: `\let\a\imareallyundefinedcommand` would  work too.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, thanks; actually it looks like `etoolbox` defines exactly the `\undef` command for which I asked (taking a control sequence, rather than a name, as its argument).

Comment: @LSpice: See egreg's answer to a former question of mine:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199692/are-end-macro-names-reserved-in-latex2e -- it's somewhat related

Comment: @LSpice `\newcommand` and `\DeclareMathOperator` rely on `\@ifdefinable` which considers a command undefined in the following two cases: (1) it currently has no meaning; (2) it is equivalent to `\relax`; the same command rejects command names starting with `\end...`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, thanks for the pointer, but that answer seems to be more about the mechanism by which `LaTeX` *implements* this check.  (Indeed, I noticed that `\renewcommand` proceeds simply by `\let`ting `\@ifdefinable` to `\@rc@ifdefinable`, and wondered if that might be appropriate; but that clobbers `\@ifdefinable` for everyone, and so I think `\let`ting the one relevant symbol to `\relax` is probably better.)

Comment: @LSpice: Yes, it was just for more information ;-)

Comment: @LSpice I'm not sure about your problem with `\rc@ifdefinable`. But `\let\a\relax` is really what you're looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to undo a `\def` (i.e., Need a `\undef` capability)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20655/5764)

Comment: @greg, yes, I agree—it appeared about 5 minutes after I posted my question, in a comment by Sigur.

Comment: @Werner, I agree that it looks like the same *question*, but I don't think that it really is a duplicate (except in the sense that the poser of that question knew the answer to this one).  As Sigur, egreg, and others point out, the answer to my question is just "`\let` `\a` to `\relax`", whereas that poster specifically mentions that `\let`ting to `\relax` *didn't* work.