# How to use Programming possibilities of LaTeX

Tags: programming

How do `\newcommand`, `\newcommand*`, `\renewcommand`, `\renewcommand*`, `\newenvironment`, `\newenvironment*`, `\renewenvironment`, `\newenvironment*` work and what is difference between them?

Comment: `\newcommand{\foo}{This prints the text here}` simply define the command `\foo` which is a kind of shortcut for *This prints the text here*. So you can use `and so \foo\ says that...`

Comment: Open a console or command window and type `texdoc latex2e` then check section 13

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/whats-the-difference-between-newcommand-and-newcommand

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros#New_commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this to satisfy the OP ...

The whole bunch of macro definition commands are quite connected:

- `\newcommand{\foo}[num_of_args][opt first arg value]{% definition}`
  defines `\foo`
- `\newcommand*{\foo}[num_of_args][opt first arg value]{% definition}`
  defines `\foo` but does not allow for parbreaks in the arguments.
- `\renewcommand{\foo}` redefines an already existing command `\foo`
- `\renewcommand*{\foo}` redefines `\foo`, with the `no-parbreak` limitation.
- `\DeclareRobustCommand` with the same syntax as `\newcommand` etc. which makes the command robust (i.e. protected/not expandable).

In addition (hidden) `\newcommand` and it's relatives define automatically `\endfoo`, so it's not possible to say `\newcommand{\endfoo}` itself. For more on this see my question [Are \end.... macro names reserved in LaTeX2e?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199692/are-end-macro-names-reserved-in-latex2e)

The environment commands:
 - `\newenvironment{fooenv}[num_of_args]{first opt arg]{%
     startcode}{endcode}` defines an environment named `fooenv`, i.e. it can be used with `\begin{fooenv}...\end{fooenv}`. The content between this pair is grouped, i.e. `\(re)newcommand` etc, length changes are applied only within this pair and not visible outside, i.e. safe (unless `\global` is not used
 - `\renewenvironment` redefines an existing environment
 - `\newenvironment*` and `\renewenvironment*` are applied with the `no-parbreak` limit.

In addition, there is `\providecommand` (same syntax as `\newcommand`) which can used to be sure that some command is really defined. If it's already defined, then `\providecommand` does nothing.

The machine behind all is the basic TeX `\def` command.
In addition, see [Difference between \newcommand and \newcommand*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/whats-the-difference-between-newcommand-and-newcommand)

Alternatives from `etoolbox` and `xparse`

- The `etoolbox` package establishes the `\(re)newrobustcmd*` for making robust commands.
- `xparse` package: `\NewDocumentCommand`, `\RenewDocumentCommand`, `\ProvideDocumentCommand`, `\NewDocumentEnvironment` and `\ProvideDocumentEnvironment` and `\DeclareDocumentEnvironment` are robust versions with a better argument handling than `\newcommand` etc. There is an expandable `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` too, which should be used with care (as stated in the `xparse` manual)