# What's wrong with my newcommand?

Tags: macros, parameters

I defined a question macro, then made it successively fancier.  Right now, three macro should define a short hand for the following:

```
\section{Questions}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Q1...
\item Q2...
\end{enumerate}
\section{Exercises}
\begin{enumerate}
\item exercise 1
\item exercise 2
\end{enumerate}
\href{my.url.goes/here/specific}{Take the quiz}
```

The three commands defined to do this are:

```
\newcommand{\qqq}{\section{Question}\begin{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\exer}{\end{enumerate}\section{Exercises}\begin{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\endexer}[1]{\end{enumerate}\href{my.url.com/path/{#1}}{Take the quiz}}
```

A sample call to make this happen:

```
\qqq
\item What is 2+3?
\exer
\item Write a program to compute 2+3
\endexer{123}
```

should generate the url:

my.url.com/path/123

The error is:

! LaTeX Error: Command \endexer already defined.
                  Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

I am not posting the MWE because I think this is a stupid syntax error based on something I am missing about \newcommand, but if I'm wrong, I will create an MWE and add it here.

Comment: The argument to `\endexer` goes in {}. But rather sake of code readability I'd recommend making this as environments instead. It gives the code a better structure

Comment: Whoops! I tried it both ways.  I will replace it, it still doesn't work

Comment: You can not define a command starting with `\end` using `\newcommand` But it  _always_ helps if you provide an example that reproduces the error rather than make people spot errors by eye.

Comment: there you are, you added the error message `Or name \end... illegal` which is telling you exactly that, you can not define `\endexer` this way.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199692/are-end-macro-names-reserved-in-latex2e

Comment: @David, I can't edit your comment, but it was ambiguous.  You meant the name of a newcommand could not begin with \end (which I know now) but that was completely unobvious since the command contents also began with \end.  The error message refers to p.192 of "the manual."  What manual is that?  I looked on latex-project.org and there are commercial books, nothing obviously a latex manual.

Comment: @Dov Leslie Lamport's "LaTeX: a document preparation system" (book from Addison-Wesley)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first problem you have is that you cannot create a macro starting with `\end...` when using `\newcommand`. This check is defined inside the LaTeX kernel as part of an `\@ifdefinable` condition. To circumvent this you need to use TeX directives. That is,

```
\def\endexer#1{<stuff>}
```

rather than

```
\newcommand{\endexer}[1]{<stuff>}
```

Secondly, the `\newcommand` syntax has the following structure (see [`source2e.pdf`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf)):

```
\newcommand*{\foo}[<i>][<j>]{<text>}
```

- `*` is optional
- `\foo` is the command to be created
- `<i>` is the number of arguments to gobble (up to 9); this references mandatory or a possible optional argument
- `<j>` is the default value of the first optional argument (if it exists does not exist); can only have one
- `<text>` is the macro definition when using `\foo`

For `\newcommand{\foo}[1]{stuff #1}` you would use it as `\foo{<stuff>}`, not `\foo[<stuff>]`. This latter usage would have required a definition of `\foo` of the form

```
\newcommand{\foo}[1][]{<stuff>}
```

Note the second set of `[]`, denoting that `\foo` takes an optional argument (that is empty by default/if not specified).

Specific to your case, use `\endexer{123}`, not `\endexer[123]`.

---

Here is a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\qqq}{\section{Question}\begin{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\exer}{\end{enumerate}\section{Exercises}\begin{enumerate}}
\def\endexer#1{\end{enumerate}\href{my.url.com/path/{#1}}{Take the quiz}}
\begin{document}

\qqq
\item What is $2+3$?
\exer
\item Write a program to compute $2+3$.
\endexer{123}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any downside to using tex rather than latex in this case?

Comment: @Dov: No, LaTeX is built on TeX. LaTeX just has an additional check to for this kind of thing (hence the discouraged approach).

Comment: @Dov It is better to use a different name (and so follow latex conventions) rather than use `\def`

Comment: Thanks! Yes, not just interested in fixing the problem, trying to learn "how it's done" in Late.  I can't believe "the manual" is a commercial book on an open source product! Yuck!

Answer (score 5):

The names beginning with `\end`.... are reserved for implementing the end codes of environments, so you can not define `\endexer` with `\newcommand`. You could call the command `\stopexer` or `\exerend` or anything else that does not start with `\end`.

Answer (score 3):

While I strongly discourage the use of `newcommand`s for such cases, here is a more-readable way of doing it:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\qqq}[1]{\section{Question}\begin{enumerate}#1\end{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\exer}[2]{\section{Exercises}\begin{enumerate}#1\end{enumerate} \href{my.url.com/path/{#2}}{Take the quiz}}

\begin{document}

\qqq{%
\item Q1 ...
\item Q2 ...}

\exer{%
\item exercise 1
\item exercise 2}
{path/to/quiz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are repeating this, however, I recommend just adding a shortcut macro which can be called by pressing two keyboard buttons. Hiding the real syntax make it harder to fix bugs later and makes your code error prone. It is always a good practice to make your `LaTeX` code explicit.

Comment: +1 for saying that making code explicit is "always a good practice".