# Where is the LaTeX manual?

Tags: documentation, latex-base

Helpful members of the community just solved my problem with `\newcommand`:

[What's wrong with my newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246729/whats-wrong-with-my-newcommand)

But in trying to solve it, I got an error message referring to p. 192 of "the manual". I would like to look up the error myself.

I am compiling under Windows using the command:

```
latexmk -pdf file.tex
```

I cannot find a link to a manual on `latex-project.org`. There are links to books which are published commercially, but surely that is not what the error messages refer to?

The not-so-short guide has fewer than 192 pages, so that's obviously not it.

Comment: Let me make a guess: It's an error message about an already defined command?

Comment: @christian That's right.  My question was answered, but I am trying to find out how to look up the error for myself

Comment: I think it's the original manual made by Leslie Lamport himself: LaTeX: A document preparation system

Comment: Which also happens to be fewer than 192 pages, if memory serves :-)

Comment: It always strucked me, why does LaTeX source (still) point to a non-accessible manual (at least for free, if I'm not mistaken)?

Comment: @Manuel For example: There is stability to think about (the message is at least 20 years old). Lamport's book remains the official manual text. I don't imagine the team want to write a new manual which essentially has to say the same as Lamport has already covered. ...

Comment: @JosephWright Probably right, still… the fact that it's not free and nowhere accessible (the source, like The TeXBook), is not entirely clear in my mind.

Comment: @Manuel The source of _The TeXbook_ is available to let people learn the coding techniques, not to use as a reference. I suspect DEK expected people would buy it or borrow from a library as well as having the source, not using the latter as an alternative.

Comment: @JosephWright May be a misconception from me, but I thought he didn't want us to compile it but no problem with searching its source (but as you say, it's probable that he expected us not even to search, *per se*, the source).

Comment: Even if "the manual" is commercial, the fact that there isn't a link to it on that site is kind of crazy.  How is one to figure out what "the manual" is?  Kudos to you stackexhange gurus!

Comment: BTW there exists a free version of the [LATEX:  An unofficial reference manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/latex2e-help-texinfo/latex2e.pdf) for your info which is not the _Official_ Manual like Leslie Lamport, LaTeX: A Document Preparation System Book.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Where can I find a manual for learning the fundamental background of LaTeX source?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/120820/5764)

Comment: It's on my shelf, by *The TeXbook* and *The LaTeX Companion*.  :-)

Comment: @Werner I think this question is sufficiently distinct to not be a dupe: it's very much focussed on 'the manual' as meant by the LaTeX2e kernel error message.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The 'manual' for LaTeX is *LaTeX: A Document Preparation System* by Leslie Lamport. This is as you observe a commercial book and one is therefore expected to visit a bookshop or library to obtain a copy. As you might also note, much of the same information as in Lamport's book is available in one or another free form (and other commercial offerings).

To understand why the manual is a book, it's worth remembering that LaTeX was first written in the 1980s based on software developed in the late 1970s to early 1980s. It's also worth remembering that (La)TeX is a typesetting system. At the time it was written, there were no electronic formats for reading documents on-screen, and printing a long document meant getting it done using a very expensive machine. As such, most software came with a proper manual. LaTeX is free, so the only way to pay for the cost of such a book was to charge for the book. (The same remains true for TeX itself, where the only way to get Knuth's manual is to buy *The TeXbook*.)

The LaTeX kernel is very stable, and so that message probably dates to code written by Lamport, with perhaps an update to the page number for LaTeX2e (1994). (Page 192 of Lamport's book does indeed describe the formal syntax for `\newcommand`.) Writing a new official manual would be a lot of work. (I'd also say the assumption that to be proficient with a complex system such as LaTeX you should read some read documentation remains sensible.)

Comment: IMO In page `43` line `219` of  [source2e V1.2n, 29/09/2014](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) the LaTeX error message `see p.192 of the manual` might be changed to `See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation` to avoid any confusion for user or even `See p.192 of Leslie Lamport LaTeX manual for explanation` to be more precise.

Comment: Just a light comment. I recently read some articles referenced by Babara Beeton where it is implied that LaTeX was around already in 1982.

Comment: @MartinArgerami The LaTeX2.09 file `ltplain.tex` has comment `Created 29 October 1985 from plain version 1.5CM`, which gives us an approximate date. Real take-up of LaTeX I believe started in the late 1980s.

Comment: @JosephWright: take a look at [this article](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb04-2/tb08letters.pdf), published in Sept 1983. On page 95 you can read "LaTeX is already available"; it is also mentioned in others letters in the article. It is hard to claim that it was "written in the mid 80s".

Comment: Now we are in a smartphone era in which screen readers are ubiquitous. Printing is no longer needed so it should be free.

Comment: @FriendlyGhost The text is still copyright (like many texts). I'm afraid if I want to properly read something I want it in printed form, so free or not dead trees will be involved.

Answer (score 12):

The manual which the error message refers to is

> Leslie Lamport, LaTeX: A Document Preparation System (second edition)

published by Addison-Wesley. The publisher's page is at

http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/product/LaTeX-A-Document-Preparation-System/9780201529838.page

Answer (score 3):

This does only partially answer the question, but just notes where the error messages comes from: `latex.ltx`

```
\gdef\@notdefinable{%
 \@latex@error{%
   Command \@backslashchar\reserved@a\space
   already defined.\MessageBreak
   Or name \@backslashchar\@qend... illegal,
   see p.192 of the manual}\@eha}
```

The page number is coded into the error message, but does not specify which manual is meant actually.

Under `texlive/doc/latex/base/manual.pdf` we just find errata to the 2nd edition, which does not give any clue.

Looking into `source2e.pdf`, we find nothing really connected to this.

After using google, I found that it is fact the Book by

> Leslie Lamport: LaTeX A Document preparation system.

(I found a link where a scanned copy of that book is available)

For reasons of copyright issues, I won't provide the link here.

Basic summary of the relevant page 192:

It's about the commands

- `\newcommand`
- `\renewcommand`
- `\providecommand`,

effectively stating, that a command name must not be defined before to be used with `\newcommand` etc.

So if the error message occurs, the command has been defined before already.

Comment: Of course it does not give any glue :) hehehe

Comment: @Manuel: Just a joke ;-) (No, a typo)