# What is the LaTeX manual and how can I see a particular page of it?

Tags: errors, documentation

Any of us, especially me, usually get error messages like:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \c@XXX already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
```

Where is the LaTeX Manual the error is talking about!?

How can I have a look at p. 192, of the named Manual?

I am using XeTeX came with TeXLive 2013, on an Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

My question is:

Isn't better to make a copy of the manual available to all!
Just takes few more MegaBytes comparing to a GigaByte distribution is nothing!

At least refer us to a publicly available reference instead of a commercial (of course very valuable but also many parts of almost out dated) book.

Comment: It's a book: _LaTeX: A Document Preparation System_ by Leslie Lamport (I am pretty sure this has come up before: I'll try to find it).

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246743/73

Comment: do we have a copy of (a `.dvi` or `.pdf` form of) it in our distributions? _i.e._ can we have it using `texdoc`?

Comment: You can buy it from nowadays: http://www.informit.com/store/latex-a-document-preparation-system-9780201529838. We've had this before: like many older pieces of software, LaTeX dates from a time when a 'manual' really did mean something in print, and as free software the only way for the author to pay for that was to sell the book.

Comment: See my post and related discussion on the earlier question, BTW

Comment: so there is no way to have a quick look to the page?