# How to go beyond the impossibility to create a command whose name starts with "\end"

Tags: macros

The following simple file gets an error during compilation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\enda}{E}
\begin{document}
dddd
\end{document}
```

The error message is:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \enda already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.2 \newcommand{\enda}{E}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

It seems that what ever I put after `\end` (say `\endb`, `\endklghfsgfljs` or whatever valid command name) Latex will produce the same error.
When the `d` of `end` is changed into another letter (say, `s`) this seems to go fine.

How do I define a command with the name I want?

**Note:** my question is not whether this is a reserved word but how to bypass the obstruction. A slightly different question is [are-end-macro-names-reserved-in-latex2e](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199692/are-end-macro-names-reserved-in-latex2e). I couldn't find this question with my intentions in mind. I expect that somebody stumbling upon the same problem as me would find this question more easily than the one in the link.

Answer (score 16):

This is 'by design' due to the way environments work. You can though use the TeX `\def` primitive

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\enda{\operatorname{End}}
\begin{document}
dddd \enda
\end{document}
```

with the proviso that an environment called `a` would be an issue!

Comment: The original macro name was endomorphisms so I think I'm safe :)

Comment: @TTFarreo Sure: I have `\endo` for work reasons ...

Comment: @TTFarreo endomorphisms are safe enough if you keep them refrigerated, but make sure you use them within 24 hours of opening the packaging ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can exploit the fact that `\NewDocumentCommand` doesn't check for initial `\end`, but only disallows defining *existing* (that is, already explicitly defined) commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newendcommand}{smO{0}om}
 {
  \cs_if_exist:NTF #2
   {% don't want to redefine anyway
    \newcommand{#2}{}%
   }
   {
    \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
     {% short
      \tl_set:Nn \l__farreo_newendcommand_arg_tl { m }
     }
     {% long
      \tl_set:Nn \l__farreo_newendcommand_arg_tl { +m }
     }
    \farreo_newendcommand:nnnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } { #5 }
   }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__farreo_newendcommand_arg_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \farreo_newendcommand:nnnn
 {
  \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #3 }
   {% no optional argument
    \exp_args:NNx
    \NewExpandableDocumentCommand
    #1
    { \prg_replicate:nn { #2 } { \l__farreo_newendcommand_arg_tl } }
    { #4 }
   }
   {
    \exp_args:NNx
    \NewDocumentCommand
    #1
    {
     \exp_not:n { +O{#3} }
     \prg_replicate:nn { #2 - 1 } { \l__farreo_newendcommand_arg_tl }
    }
    { #4 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newendcommand\endenumerate[1]{x} % <-- error
\newendcommand{\endo}{E}
\newendcommand{\endopt}[2][OPT]{{\ttfamily\#1=#1, \#2=\detokenize{#2}}}
\newendcommand*{\endstar}[1]{{\ttfamily\#1=#1}}

\begin{document}

\endo

\endopt{x}

\endopt[Y]{x\par}

\endstar{x\par} % <-- error

\end{document}
```

Of course you could directly use `\NewDocumentCommand`; it requires a different syntax than `\newcommand`, but it's much more powerful.

The instruction `\newendcommand{\endenumerate}{}` raises the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \endenumerate already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

The last call `\endstar{x\par}` instead raises the error

```
Runaway argument?
{x
! Paragraph ended before \endstar  was complete.
```

because `\endstar` has been called with `\newendcommand*`. To the contrary, `\endopt` accepts `\par` in its arguments.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`\newcommand` internally uses `\@ifdefinable` for checking whether a command is definable.

Beneath other things `\@ifdefinable` checks whether the first three letters of the command-name in question are `e`, `n`, `d`. For doing this, `\ifx`-comparison is done to a macro `\@qend` whose expansion yields these letters as explicit character tokens of category code 12 (other).

If you wish, you can temporarily override the definition of `\@qend` with a token sequence which does not occur in the "stringification" of the command-name desired by you:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\savedqend{}
\newcommand\changeqend[1]{\let\savedqend=\@qend \long\def\@qend{#1}}%
\newcommand\restoreqend{\let\@qend=\savedqend}%
\makeatother

\changeqend{ThisStuffIsNotOfCatcodeTwelveButOfCatCodeEleven}
\newcommand{\endomorphism}{Endomorphism}
\restoreqend

\begin{document}
\endomorphism
\end{document}
```

But you can also use `\renewcommand` if you insist in having something with LaTeX syntax:

`\renewcommand` doesn't use `\@ifdefinable`, thus doesn't check the first three letters of the command-name in question. Just assign a dummy-definition via `\def`, then perform `\renewcommand`.

The following code provides macros `\mynicenewcommand` and `\myniceprovidecommand` which do these things for you. `\renewcommand` and `\DeclareRobustCommand` don't require `mynice`‑variants as they don't use `\@ifdefinable`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\myniceprovidecommand[1]{%
  \edef\reserved@a{\expandafter\@gobble\string#1}%
  \@ifundefined\reserved@a{\def#1{Dummy}\renewcommand#1}%
                          {\renewcommand\reserved@a}%
}%
\newcommand\mynicenewcommand[1]{%
  \edef\reserved@a{\expandafter\@gobble\string#1}%
  \@ifundefined\reserved@a{\def#1{Dummy}\renewcommand}%
                          {\newcommand}%
  #1%
}%
\makeatother

\mynicenewcommand{\endomorphism}{Endomorphism}

\myniceprovidecommand{\endomorphism}{EndomorphismB}

\begin{document}
\endomorphism
\end{document}
```