# How to end appendix?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, appendices

Is there a way to end the `\appendix`?

Specifically, I have a file like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{one}
Should be section1
\section{two}
Should be section 2
\appendix
\section{a1}
Should be A

\section{b}
should be B

\section{three}
Should be 3

\end{document}
```

and I can't seem to get the appendix to "end" in any way. I'd rather not reset the section counter to a specific number manually because I might go back and add several sections above the appendix later.

Answer (score 9):

The `\appendix` command is a one way switch. In `article.cls` it does:

```
\setcounter{section}{0}% Resets the section counter
\setcounter{subsection}{0}% and the subsection counter
\gdef\thesection{\@Alph\c@section}% and makes \thesection with Alph numbering
```

you cannot simply revert this because the section numbering is lost.

You can create a counter `savesection` to store the section number, then create an `\unappendix` command that reverts the changes done by `\appendix`.

Additionally I added a `apdxsection` counter to save the appendix numbering, so you can switch back and forth from normal sections to appendices.

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{savesection}
\newcounter{apdxsection}
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{savesection}{\value{section}}%
  \setcounter{section}{\value{apdxsection}}%
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
  \gdef\thesection{\@Alph\c@section}}
\newcommand\unappendix{\par
  \setcounter{apdxsection}{\value{section}}%
  \setcounter{section}{\value{savesection}}%
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
  \gdef\thesection{\@arabic\c@section}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{one}
Should be section1
\section{two}
Should be section 2

\appendix

\section{a}
Should be A

\section{b}
should be B

\unappendix

\section{three}
Should be 3

\appendix

\section{c}
should be C

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Calling it `endappendix` results in: `! LaTeX Error: Command \endappendix already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.` but calling it `finishappendix` works just fine.

Comment: @Alex First I called it `\unappendix`, then I thought "`\endappendix` sounds better" and changed, but then I remembered about [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/443447/134574) and reverted. You could put these definitions in a `\newenvironment` and use `\begin{appendix}...\end{appendix}`, but I think that the group created could make some mess, so I preferred to leave as two separate switches.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the standard command `\begin{appendix}` and `\end{appendix}` do work!

Comment: Using the minimal example provided by the OP, merely changing `\appendix` into a `\begin{appendix}`...`\end{appendix}` group around the 2 sections doesn't provide a solution. Nor does adding the [`appendix` package](//ctan.org/pkg/appendix) and using your suggestion. Can you elaborate on why this solution works by providing a minimal example? If not, this doesn't provide much value.